# Выборка ключевых слов в столбце mysql

Tags: php, mysql

У меня имеется таблица с таким столбцом. Как я могу сделать выборку только только ford и bmw без AND?
LIKE %ford%bmw% не работает. С помощью LIKE могу найти только одно наименование...

````
Ford Utility Police Interceptor Base
BMW Z3 2.3 Roadster
Ford F-150 Harley-Davidson
Mercedes-Benz S-Class S 550
Chevrolet Express 2500 Work Van```
````

Comment: "без AND" ......... OR

Comment: или IN ('ford', 'bmw')

Comment: А без операторов я могу это как-то сделать, используя только один общий параметр?

Comment: Если идёт поиск по подстроке - вряд ли

Comment: SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE title IN ('ford', 'bmw'); выдает 0 строк. :( Уже пытался...

Comment: SELECT * FROM cars WHERE title IN ('Ford', 'BMW'); Регистр имеет значение

Comment: IN будет искать по точному значению, у меня наименование модели с производителем в одной строке...

Comment: Поэтому OR.....

Comment: @SwaD *Регистр имеет значение* Значение имеет COLLATION. А вот ежели оно case-sensitive - тогда да, имеет значение регистр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE title REGEXP 'ford|bmw' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qN0mWMq0)

COLLATION подрихтовать в соответствии с реальными установками CHARACTER SET.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, реализовал на PHP как-то так:

```
$arr = ['ford','nissan','bmw'];


$sqlQuery = '';
foreach ($arr as $value) {
  $sqlQuery .= '(title LIKE \'%'.$value.'%\') OR ';
}
$sqlQuery = substr($sqlQuery,0,-4);
```